# prevent a form from being submitted while pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit

how can we prevent a form from being submitted while pressing enter key.

Actually I have a text box and on entering a value on that textbox and clicking enter the textbox2 will get focused.

By default on clicking the enter button the form will get submitted. So I can not get the out put. I wrote return false on onclick event of the submit button then it works. 
So I would like to know how can we prevent a form submission while pressing enter.

Comment: That answer relies on jquery; it would be nice to have one that doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking up the actual code, here's the basic theory behind how I'd do it:

Define an event handler on the document for a key being pressed to call a function.

If the key that triggered the event is the enter/return key, `return false`, otherwise `return true`.

EDIT: Looks like you already found the answer (as well as some code to do it), so my answer is somewhat unnecessary now.

Comment: I would like to see code that does what that page does, but without jquery.

Comment: Me too. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Writing 'onKeyPress' of the form like " `{ var key; if(window.event) key = window.event.keyCode; else key = e.which; //firefox return (key != 13); }` "  will work.

Answer (score 0):

what i do is add `onsubmit="return false;"` to the `<form>` tag.
this will also disable the submit button however to create a working submit button use

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:document.form.submit();" />
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
    //Form elements
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tested this? Seems like that would prevent you from submitting the form in any way, not just by pressing Enter. I could be wrong though.

Comment: It will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: writing 'onKeyPress' of the form like "
                                {
                                  var key;      
     if(window.event)
          key = window.event.keyCode;      else
          key = e.which; //firefox      

     return (key != 13);
                                }
                                "   this will work.

Comment: Yes, but if you read, he already has a return false on the submit button, so one can assume that he doesn't actually want to submit the form the normal way